# exception of type 'system.outofmemoryexception' was thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net

My page throws error exception of type 'system.outofmemoryexception' was thrown .

This happens when i press submit button in submit button there are sqlconnections with stored procedure as im populating grid with data .

It gives error when i put code in submit button. But when i put tht on page load it works good .

Can anyone help me on  this .

Thanks,
Smartdev

Comment: Without seeing the code, this is a near impossible task. My guess is that you have some code that is hitting a race condition and sucking up all the available memory...

Comment: Agreed.  Do you have an infinite loop or a unterminated recursion somewhere?

Comment: The exception includes a stacktrace - that should tell you where the error occurs, but not necessarily why. Use a debugger such a WinDbg or a memory profiler to tell you what is taking up lots of memory.

Comment: See this answer (basically the same issue) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405041/exception-of-type-system-outofmemoryexception-was-thrown/6405058#6405058

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means, that you allocated too much memory in your program. Either buy more memory in a hardware retail shop or use less memory in your program.

Comment: Buying more memory isn't the answer - An OutOfMemoryException is, in its simplest terms, pertaining to Virtual Memory. Not Physical Memory. The "use less memory" part is more apt though.

Answer (score 4):

Since my comment got upvotes...I figured I'd post it as an answer.

Without seeing all of your code, it's nearly impossible to tell you why you're getting the Exception.

That said, my guess would be that you have a race condition somehwhere in your event handler that is causing the System to run out of memory. Most likely it's either an infinite loop or an un-terminated recursive method.

Comment: justin thank you for the reply  and  u are rite i had some code running on the page load .which cleared it and one more thing was that page had more thn 1 lac records in grid view without paging . when i added paging it worked fine .is there any other way where we can increase the performance of the page while dispalying more thn one lac records

thanks again
smartdev

Answer (score 0):

Something strange is happening -- that's all I can tell you from your description.

It could be a bug third-party control.  It could be a bug in your code, it could be something "pinning" memory somewhere.  You could legitimately be out of memory...

You should post a complete stack trace of the error.  Post your memory utilization statistics.  Post some code from where you think the error is happening.

Comment: It could have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

See [Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405041/exception-of-type-system-outofmemoryexception-was-thrown/6405058#6405058) for my answer to the same question:

In short you have a recursive call somewhere in your code (and not necessarily on purpose) i.e.

```
Class A{

    ctor(){
      var a = new A();// oops!!
    }
}
```