# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I run into this exception in the middle of the project, when i press F5 to start debugging. I am using Visual Studio 2011 and the project is MCV3, EF4 and i am using Crystal report in the project.

Here is the trace of the exception:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was
>   thrown.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception
>   of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'
>   was thrown.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [OutOfMemoryException: Exception of
>   type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was
>   thrown.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +39
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection,
>   Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +132
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String
>   assemblyString, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   +144    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>   +46
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException:
>   Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was
>   thrown.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>   +618    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +209    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +130
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +178
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +94    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods()
>   +332    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost,
>   IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory,
>   HostingEnvironmentParameters
>   hostingParameters, PolicyLevel
>   policyLevel, Exception
>   appDomainCreationException) +591
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception
>   of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'
>   was thrown.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +8946484
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +97
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest
>   wr) +258

any idea on how this come up.

Comment: The exception is thrown by code inside the CLR, code that loads an assembly.  That's all that can be guessed from the stack trace.  You'd need an unmanaged debugger to see more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (possibly) have a recursive call somewhere in your code i.e.

class A
ctor(){
 CallAMethod();
}
CallAMethod()
{
  A a = new A();
}
}

EDIT: Pauli rightly points out that recursion will usually cause StackOverflowException however (and correct me if wrong) I have seen upper limits on recursion of some 80,000 calls which, should the object be large and the system limited in memory (from other reading I see it is CLR heap size not the linear address space though I assume this could come into play also), would result in a drain on resources.

Comment: I am having this problem when i tried to publish the project to a testing environment, meaning before that it was working fine. can you tell me from the exception where you see kind of recursive calls ..

Comment: The stack trace may not be helpful in the case of overflows (infinite recursion can cause all sorts of false positives.) check your code. This is almost always cause as a result of either your or a library you are using creating recursion

Comment: infinite recursion would lead to a StackOverflowException

Comment: :) You are right (though I wonder what happens if you the objects created are large and your system is low on memory - I'm sure I have had OutOfMemoryException after recursion) but in most cases StackOverflowException will be the result

Comment: Probably, StackOverflow will happen before OutOfMemory